# error: undefined method `presigned_post'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm writing a rails application with which a user can upload images. I am deploying with Heroku, and using Carrierwave and S3 to upload and store images. I have followed this [heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails#pre-signed-post) step-by-step...unfortunately I am still getting an error "undefined method `presigned_post'", and do not know how to resolve it. It seems the S3_BUCKET is not being recognized as an aws object...

Has anyone come across this problem and figured it out? Here's some code for reference:

Pictures controller:

```html
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_s3_direct_post, only: [:new, :create]

  def index
    @pictures = Picture.all
  end

  def new
    @pictures = Picture.all
    @picture = Picture.new
  end

  def create
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)

    if @picture.save
      redirect_to new_picture_path, notice: "You just uploaded a picture!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
                                                
  ...

  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:attachment)
  end

private

  def set_s3_direct_post
    @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read')
  end
end
```

New picture view:

```html
<h1>Upload a new picture</h1>
<br>
<div class="well">
  <%= form_for @picture, html: { class: 'directUpload', data: { 'form-data' => (@s3_direct_post.fields), 'url' => @s3_direct_post.url, 'host' => URI.parse(@s3_direct_post.url).host } } do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
    <%= f.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And config/environment.rb:

```html
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
# S3
S3_BUCKET='fotoes'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='secretxxxxxxxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='xxxxxxxsecretxxxxxx'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the class name for this error: "undefined method `presigned_post'"? Make sure `S3_BUCKET` is not nil.

Comment: Hi @wesley6j, the class name is "NoMethodError" in PicturesController#new... And yes, the S3_BUCKET seems to be there, but it doesn't seem to accept the presigned_post method :/

Comment: please inspect S3_BUCKET and make sure it is an instance of aws bucket. If you just added the initializer for aws-sdk, make sure to restart the server once.

Comment: That's a good point. It definitely is not... How can I fix this though?

Comment: Have you set s3-sdk according to [the guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails#s3-sdk)?

Comment: Yes, everything that is in the heroku guide I've done.

Comment: My friend and I have been pair programming. We set this up on his Windows machine and everything works fine. Now that I cloned the project to my system, OS X, I receive this same error. Did you find a fix?

Comment: Yes @Jonathan. Everything is working ok right now (it's hard to say what went wrong, but I guess a bunch of things..) Thank you for your support!

Comment: I also ran into the same problem but this other Heroku tutorial (way simpler) worked for me https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3 It works with Paperclip instead of Carrierwave and Fog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. In the end I found a different walk-through that was much simpler and effective. (The Heroku one was a little complicated and left a lot to go wrong - go figure.)

[This](https://u.osu.edu/hasnan.1/2014/03/13/rails-4-upload-image-to-s3-using-fog-and-carrierwave/) solved everything :)

edit:

1. not everything - had to complete one last step before I got the site running. Run this line in the terminal: $ heroku config:add AWS_ACCESS_KEY=value
   and $ heroku config:add AWS_SECRET_KEY=value, where the value is your S3 credentials for each, respectively.
2. This was the only combo of fog, carrierwave, rails, fog-aws gems that worked (after weeks of fussing with them):

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0'

gem 'fog', '1.34.0'

gem 'fog-aws', '0.7.6'

Answer (score 0):

@Jillian I suppose your expectation was that S3_BUCKET class should call presigned_post method which is supposed to be defined. However, it seems its not. I took a look at the heroku page containing the tutorial you followed and well you followed every instruction. I suggest you contact heroku about the documentation. However, I would keep looking into it

Comment: @ Jillian I think what @wesley6j said might help. Initializing s3-adk would help but that would be a temporal fix. Still contact heroku though.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this by updating my version of aws-sdk

```
$ bundle update aws-sdk
```